# Expected value of an increasing function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a question which came to me in my research.

The probability of an event $A$ happening is characterized by a parameter $\lambda>0$. And as $\lambda$ increases the probability of that event happening $P(A)$ decreases. There is a set of functions indexed by number of successful trials $f_{i}(\lambda)$ which are positive valued and are increasing in $\lambda$. Also $f_{i}(\lambda)$ is such that as $i$ increases they decrease, i.e., $f_{i}(\lambda)>f_{j}(\lambda)$ for $i<j$.

There will be $N$ independent trials of the experiment and the expected value of the set of functions over the $N$ trials is given by 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y(\lambda)=\sum_{i=0}^{N}{N\choose i}P(A)^{i}\cdot\left(1-P(A)\right)^{N-i}\cdot f_{i}(\lambda)
\end{eqnarray*}
I want to claim that as $\lambda$ increases, $y(\lambda)$ monotonically increases.
Even asymptotically increasing is sufficient. But I have a feeling monotonically increasing will hold.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your notation: it seems like $i$ and $j$ are the indices for both a sum and a product simultaneously.

Comment: It's like a probability tree. I'm taking all possible combinations of event $A$ happening and not happening in $N$ independent trials. I will try to edit it to make it clear.. Thanks

Comment: I have edited it and hope now it's clearer.

Comment: I started by taking the the term where $i=0$
that is $(1−P(A))^N \cdot f_{0}(\lambda)$.
This term is clearly increasing in $\lambda$ as both the probability term of event not happening N times and function $f_{0}(\lambda)$ both increase in λ. Then I notice that all other terms of the summation are positive valued as defined above and their probabilities will go to 0 as $\lambda$ increases because $P(A)$ will go to zero. So $y(\lambda)$ increases in $\lambda$.

Comment: But I'm confused as the other terms have products of probabilities where event happening probability $P(A)$ decreases and event not happening probability $(1-P(A))$ increases so I'm not sure if my argument is correct. Please let me know any other way to prove it or disprove it.

Comment: Without any information on the relative values of $f_i(\lambda)$ when $i$ varies, this seems dubious.

Comment: Thanks Did. I do have relative values of $f_{i}(\lambda)$ They are such that as $i$ increases they decrease, i.e., $f_{i}(\lambda)>f_{j}(\lambda)$ for $i<j$. That means the less the event happens the greater the function value.

Comment: Sorry but is $i\mapsto f_i(\lambda)$ increasing or decreasing, for each fixed $\lambda$? Both versions appear on the page, at the moment.

Comment: As $i$ increases $f_{i}(\lambda)$ decreases for fixed $\lambda$. There fore $f_{0}(\lambda)$ is the largest among all $f_{i}(\lambda)$ for a fixed lambda. I corrected the typo. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $f_i(\lambda)$ as $f(i,\lambda)$ and $P(A)$ as $p(\lambda)$. Then $y(\lambda)=E(f(X_{p(\lambda)},\lambda))$ where, for every $p$, $X_p$ is binomial $(N,p)$. One assumes that, for every $\lambda$, the sequence $f(\ ,\lambda):i\mapsto f(i,\lambda)$ is nondecreasing and that, for every $i$, the function $f(i,\ ):\lambda\mapsto f(i,\lambda)$ is nonincreasing (or rather, I hope this is what one assumes). Furthermore, the function $\lambda\mapsto p(\lambda)$ is nonincreasing. Finally, note that, by coupling, one can assume that $X_{p}\leqslant X_q$ almost surely, for every $p\leqslant q$.

Let $\lambda\leqslant\mu$. Then, $p(\lambda)\geqslant p(\mu)$ hence $X_{p(\lambda)}\geqslant X_{p(\mu)}$ almost surely hence, almost surely, 
$$
f(X_{p(\lambda)},\lambda)\geqslant f(X_{p(\lambda)},\mu)\geqslant f(X_{p(\mu)},\mu).
$$
In particular, $y(\lambda)\geqslant y(\mu)$, that is, $\lambda\mapsto y(\lambda)$ is nonincreasing.

**Edit:** The fact that $X_p$ is binomial $(N,p)$ and $X_q$ is binomial $(N,q)$, with $p\leqslant q$ says next to nothing, a priori, on the pointwise comparison of $X_p$ and $X_q$ since these random variables might even be defined on different probability spaces. But it happens that one can *couple* them, that is, to realize them on a common probability space, in a way such that the event $[X_p\leqslant X_q]$ has full probability.

This is a very general, and very powerful, idea and in the present case the construction can be made explicit, as follows. Start from $N$ i.i.d. random variables $(U_n)_{1\leqslant n\leqslant N}$, uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. For every $p$ in $(0,1)$, let
$$
X_p=\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbf 1_{U_n\leqslant p}.
$$
Then each $X_p$ is binomial $(N,p)$ and $X_p\leqslant X_q$ almost surely, for every $p\leqslant q$.

Comment: Hello did. I have for every $i$,  $f(i,\lambda)$ is increasing in $\lambda$ and for every$\lambda$,  $f(i,\lambda)$ is decreasing in $i$

Comment: Hello Did. I changed the increasing and decreasing properties according to the problem. Please check if it is still correct.

Comment: Hello Did. Could you please explain what you mean "by coupling, one can assume that $X_{p}\leqslant X_q$ almost surely, for every $p\leqslant q$". Thank you.

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $